# Minimum value when $abc+ab+4bc+9ca=144$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, optimization, quadratics, maxima-minima

If $a,b,c$ are non-negative real numbers such that $abc+ab+4bc+9ca=144$, find the minimum value of $a+b+c$.

I tried with Lagrange multipliers. I got the system:

$bc+b+9c=ca+a+4c=ab+4b+9a$

Replacing in the condition, I found four solutions, but only one $(4,0,4)$ is non-negative. So the minimum value is $8$. My question is, can this be done without Lagrange Multipliers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a+b+c<8,$ $a=kx$, $b=ky$ and $c=kz$ such that $k>0$ and $x+y+z=8.$

Thus, $$k(x+y+z)<8,$$ which gives $0<k<1.$

Thus, $$144=k^3xyz+k^2(xy+4yz+9zx)<xyz+xy+4yz+9zx,$$ which is a contradiction because we'll prove now that
$$xyz+xy+4yz+9zx\leq144.$$ 
Indeed, we need to prove that: $$xyz+\frac{(x+y+z)(xy+4yz+9zx)}{8}\leq\frac{144(x+y+z)^3}{512}$$ or
$$9(x+z)(x-z)^2+y(23x+11z)(x-z)+y^2(9y+23x+11z)\geq0,$$ for which it's enough to prove that
$$y^2(23x+11z)^2-36y^2(x+z)(23x+11z)\leq0,$$ which is obvious.

Id est, $$a+b+c\geq8.$$
The equality occurs for $a=c=4$ and $b=0,$ which says that we got a minimal value.

Answer (score 2):

You can get there without resorting on Lagrange multipliers.

First the constraint $\,144=abc+ab+4bc+9ca\,$ is transformed into a more suitable expression:
Divide it by $36$ and rescale variables by $\,\alpha=\frac a4, \beta=\frac b9,$ and $\gamma=c.$ This leads to
$$\begin{align*}4 \:=\:\alpha\beta\gamma & +\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma + \gamma\alpha\quad
\big| +\alpha\beta +\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha +4(\alpha+\beta+\gamma) +8 \\[1.6ex]
\iff\;\sum_{\text{cyc}}(\alpha+2)(\beta+2) & \:=\:(\alpha+2)(\beta+2)(\gamma+2)\quad\Big|\:\cdot\frac1{\text{RHS}}\\
\iff\;\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac1{\alpha+2} & \:=\:1\tag{1}
\end{align*}$$
Next apply the Cauchy–Bunyakovsky–Schwarz inequality and exploit $(1)$ to obtain
$$\begin{align*}
(2+3+1)^2 & \:=\:
\left(2\sqrt{\alpha+2}\cdot\frac1{\sqrt{\alpha+2}}
\,+\,3\sqrt{\beta+2}\cdot\frac1{\sqrt{\beta+2}}
\,+\,\sqrt{\gamma+2}\cdot\frac1{\sqrt{\gamma+2}}\right)^2 \\[1ex]
& \:\leqslant\: 4(\alpha+2)+9(\beta+2)+\gamma+2 \\[2ex]
\iff\quad 8 & \:\leqslant\:4\alpha+9\beta+\gamma \:=\:a+b+c
\end{align*}$$
Finally, one has equality only if one argument vector is a scalar multiple of the other. Thus,
$$2\sqrt{\alpha+2}=\frac\lambda{\sqrt{\alpha+2}}\;
\text{ and so on, or }\;2(\alpha+2)=\lambda=3(\beta+2) = \gamma+2\,,$$ 
which yields $\lambda=6$ using $(1)$. Hence $(a,b,c)=(4,0,4)\,$
is the unique minimising solution.

Answer (score 1):

[Hanno's CS solution is much more instructive, so read that. I was pleasantly surprised that this approach worked, so I posted it.]

1/ First, suppose $c$ is fixed, and we want to minimize $a+b$. The condition is equivalent to

$$ (c+1) ab + (4c) b + (9c) a = 144, $$

which we factorize (via Simon's Favorite Factoring Trick)  to

$$[ (c+1 ) a + 4c ] [ (c+1) b + 9c ] = 144(c+1) + 36 c^2, $$

and applying AM-GM on the LHS (both terms are non-negative), we get that

$$  [ (c+1 ) a + 4c ] + [ (c+1) b + 9c ] \geq 2 \sqrt{ 144(c+1) + 36 c^2 } =  12(c+2),  $$

which simplifies to (We divide by $ c+1 \geq 0$)

$$ a+b \geq \frac{ -c + 24 } { c+1} , $$

or that

$$ a + b +c \geq  \frac{ c^2 + 24 } { c+1}.  $$

Equality holds when $ (c+1) a + 4c  = (c+1)b + 9c $, or that $ a-b = \frac{5c}{c+1}$.

2/ Show that on $ c \geq 0 $,  we have $ \frac{ c^2 + 24 } { c+1 } \geq 8 $ with equality at $ c = 4$.
This can be done through differentiation or through clever AM-GM (if you want to avoid calculus).

3/ Hence, conclude that $ a+b+c \geq 8$, with equality when $c = 4, a - b = 4$.
We substitute this into the original condition, and solve the quadratic to get the equality case of  $ a = 4, b = 0, c = 4$ (reject negative cases ).

Notes

- There was nothing special about fixing $c$. We could also have proceeded with $a$ or $b$ fixed, and arrived at the same conclusion.

  - In fact, if we did the similar calculations, we could determine the values of $a = 4, b = 0, c = 4$, and then verify that the original condition is satisfied.
- Hanno's observation about transforming to remove coefficients would have simplified this writeup.

Comment: What is SFFT? And, so it is similar for finding the minimum of $a+b+c$ subject to $p_1 abc+p_2 ab+p_3bc + p_4ca= 1$?

Comment: @RiverLi Simon's Favorite Factoring Trick. I do believe that this approach will work for that too. That the RHS turned out to be a perfect square was somewhat surprising. I'm not certain how dependent that is on certain terms being a square though. $\quad$ Separately, how did you find that I posted this solution? I though this was quite buried.

Comment: It is the first time I've heard Simon's Favorite Factoring Trick which is helpful. Because inequality is in the list of "Watched Tags".

Comment: SFFT is more often used in solving diophantine equations, as the factorization then allows us to hunt down prime divisors etc. EG search for SFFT on MSE, Of course that idea can be exploited elsewhere, like the idea that $(c+1)a +4 c = \frac{ (6c+12)^2}{(c+a)b+9c}$ could be derived from the condition seems surprising at first glance.   $\quad$ Ah, do you toggle over to active? I usually just look at newest.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, for active and newest both.